# Automatic Population of table

Tags: tables, automation

I'm a Newbie to LaTeX. I'm looking for a way to make a Bill of Materials list (automatically) from the contents available in the document.

In the below example, I've shown what the document will contain & what output is required for me.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Eg:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{booktabs}  
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\usepackage{lscape}
\begin{document}

\section{Need to Auto Generate Table from these Tables}

\subsection{Chap 1}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Parts}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{.8\linewidth}{l X X r}
\toprule
Item No. &  Part Number     &   Description                 &   Qty. \\
\midrule
1        &      Comp 1          &   ABC &   X \\

2        &     Comp 2   &   CDE             &   XX \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\clearpage

\subsection{Chap 2}

\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Parts}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{.8\linewidth}{l X X r}

\toprule
Item No. &  Part Number     &   Description                 &   Qty. \\
\midrule
1        &      Comp 3          &   BCD &   XX \\

2        &     Comp 4   &   COD             &   XXX \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\subsection{Reference (section not to be populated in output)}
     \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ c X X r}
      \toprule
      Description &   Manufacturer    &   Model \# &   Internal Part \#\\
      \midrule
      Comp 1  &   Jack \& co  &   V1  &   -   \\
      Comp 2  &   Jill \& co  & V2    & A1B2\\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \clearpage

\begin{landscape}
\subsection{Bill - (Required final output)}
        \subsection*{Example}\\
        \begin{table}[h]
            \toprule
            \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ c X l l r}
                \emph{Quantity} &
                    \emph{Description} &
                    \emph{Manufacturer} &
                    \emph{Model \#} &
                    \emph{Internal Part \#}\\  
                    \midrule
                     X & 
                     Comp 1 &
                      Jack \& co &
                      V1 &
                      - \\
                        \hline
                    XX & 
                     Comp 2 &
                      Jill \& co &
                      V2 &
                      A1B2 \\
                      \hline
%etc
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabularx}
        \end{table}
         \clearpage
    \end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Edit - "Kindly tell me if this is actually possible."